# Warning in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, output, warnings

[image]

When I run my code, it returns many warnings but I still have expected output with no line error. I consider whether or not I have to fix my code.

This is my code for this exercise:
Assume that a railway train has N railroad cars attached together
such as car1, car2, car3, ..., carN . A train can be considered as a list and each car corresponds to a node in this list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Structure for cars of train
typedef struct _Car {
    int capacity;
    char id;
    int passengers;
    struct Car *pnext;
}Car;

// Structure for train
typedef struct _Train {
    int size;
    Car *pHead;
    Car *pTail;
}Train;

// Initialize the train with no element
void initTrain(Train *train) {
    train->size = 0;
    train->pHead = NULL;
    train->pTail = NULL;
}

// Initialize car
Car *initCar(char id, int capacity, int passengers) {
    Car *car = (Car*)malloc(sizeof *car);
    car->capacity = capacity;
    car->id = id;
    car->passengers = passengers;
    car->pnext = NULL;
    return car;
}

// Find a car in the train by its ID
Car *findCarById(Train *train, char id) {
    Car *ptr = train->pHead;
    
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        if (ptr->id == id) {
            return ptr;
        }
        ptr = ptr->pnext;
    }
    
    // Car with the specified ID not found
    return NULL;
}

// Verify whether a list is not empty
int isEmpty(Train *train) {
    return (train->size == 0);
}

// Add new car: 2 cases
// ptr points to a specific car
void addCar(Train *train, char id, int capacity, int passengers, Car *ptr) 
{
    Car *newcar = initCar(id, capacity, passengers);

    // If the train list is empty -> new car will be added to the list head
    if (isEmpty(train)) {
        train->size++;
        train->pHead = newcar;
        train->pTail = newcar;
    }
    else {
    // New car is linked after a specific car (ptr)
        if (ptr == NULL) { 
            newcar->pnext = train->pHead;
            train->pHead = newcar;
        }
        else {
            newcar->pnext = ptr->pnext;
            ptr->pnext = newcar;
            if (ptr == train->pTail) {
                train->pTail = newcar;
            }
        }
    train->size++;
    }
}

// Remove empty cars: 2 cases
void removeEmptycar(Train *train, int val) 
{
    // If the first car is empty and removed
    Car *ptr = train->pHead;
    if (ptr->passengers == val) {
        train->pHead = ptr->pnext;
        free(ptr);
        train->size--;
        return;
    }

    // If any car is removed, a new link is created between the previous car and the next car
    Car *q = ptr->pnext;
    int count = 1;
    while ((ptr->passengers != val) && (count < trainLength(train))) {
        q = ptr; // update q is current node so that q always points to the previous node of ptr
        ptr = ptr->pnext;
    }
    if (ptr != NULL) { // check if the node containing the value was found
        q->pnext = ptr->pnext;
        train->size--;
        free(ptr);
    }
}

// Length of train
int trainLength(Train *train) {
    return train->size;
}

// Display all cars's information
void display(Train *train) {
    Car *ptr = train->pHead;
    printf("Information:\n");
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("Car: %c - Capacity: %d - Passengers: %d\n",ptr->id,ptr->capacity,ptr->passengers);
        ptr = ptr->pnext;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    Train train;
    initTrain(&train);

    addCar(&train, 'A', 50, 34, NULL);
    addCar(&train, 'B', 45, 39, NULL);
    addCar(&train, 'C', 60, 0, NULL);
    printf("Before:\n");
    display(&train);

    Car *newcar = findCarById(&train, 'A'); // find specific car 'A' to use it as a reference
    if (newcar != NULL) {
        addCar(&train, 'E', 8, 6, newcar); // add car 'E' after the car 'A'
    }
    printf("After add new car:\n");
    display(&train);


    removeEmptycar(&train, 0);
    printf("After remove empty car:\n");
    display(&train);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is likely because of bugs in your code.  If you want help finding them, you need to post the code as _text_ (not pictures) here, by editing your question.

Comment: "*I consider whether or not I have to fix my code*" ... **YES, you should fix your code**, those "warnings" are in fact errors. With gcc I like to use `gcc ... -Werror ...` to make errors (and stop compilation) from all warnings.

Comment: @Lundin I have provided my code

Comment: @pmg thanks, I have fixed my code.

Answer (score 1):

Copying your code and then compiling the code, I indeed also go the compiler warnings about the "Car *" reference.  The main issue there is your code is attempting to utilize a pointer within a structure that actually hasn't been defined yet.

```
// Structure for cars of train
typedef struct _Car
{
    int capacity;
    char id;
    int passengers;
    struct Car *pnext;             /* In effect, "Car" has not been defined at this point   */
} Car;
```

So in that case, the reference needed to be to the initial definition label "_Car".

```
// Structure for cars of train
typedef struct _Car
{
    int capacity;
    char id;
    int passengers;
    struct _Car *pnext;             /* In effect, "Car" has not been defined at this point   */
} Car;
```

After making that one bit of refactoring, compilation still led to an issue with an implicit function declaration as function "trainLength()" was placed after another function that was referencing it, but there was no function prototype.

```
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Railroad/main.c|114|warning: implicit declaration of function ‘trainLength’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
```

So that function was moved up before its usage and the program compiled without errors or warnings.

```
// Length of train
int trainLength(Train *train)
{
    return train->size;
}

// Remove empty cars: 2 cases
void removeEmptycar(Train *train, int val)
{
```

So be careful of when a variable, function, pointer, or other object becomes defined and available for referencing.